# How to use the style in the tag using the thymeleaf?

Tags: css, thymeleaf

This question is about the thymeleaf style attribute question.
Don't know how to solve it.
I attached the image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsKig.png)

In this image, I'd like to put a number of value in the span tag style.
I tried to change the position of Quotation mark and also the other ways
but when I check the page source it doesn't work.
sometimes I got the 500 error.

How can I change this problem?

ex)